# Sparkline graphs strange behaviour colors at mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery plugin named [sparkline](http://jsfiddle.net/bgnswhue/1/)

If I used like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#sparkline5").sparkline([2, 8, 10, 22], {
        type: 'pie',
        height: '140',
        sliceColors: ['#1ab394', '#40e014', '#C4C5C7', '#79D2C0']
    }); 
});
```

I see that for `#C4C5C7` color, when hover it becomes white instead lighter gray...

See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgnswhue/1/

But... Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting the lighten amount like this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#sparkline5").sparkline([2, 8, 10, 22], {
        type: 'pie',
        height: '140',
        sliceColors: ['#1ab394', '#40e014', '#C4C5C7', '#79D2C0'],
        highlightLighten: 1.1
    }); 
});
```

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#interactive